# .NET Core API is giving 404 from angular app

Tags: javascript, node.js, angular, typescript, asp.net-core-webapi

I'm trying to call the method in the controller by URL, but I getting a 404 error.
What am I doing wrong? 
API End Pint: `http://localhost:5000/Home/HomeTest`

```cs
/*.net core web-api*/
namespace MyApp.Controllers
{
    Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class HomeController : ControllerBase
    {
        public HomeController()
        {}

        [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
        [HttpGet]
        public string HomeTest()
        {
            return "123";
        }
}
```

```js
/*angular*/
export class HomeComponent implements OnInit {
    constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}
    ngOnInit()
    {
        let test = "";
        test = "http://localhost:5000/api/Home/HomeTest";
        this.http.get(test).subscribe((data: any) => console.log(data), (err: any) => console.log(err));
    }
}
```

Comment: you are getting any error in console?

Comment: Do you still get the not found error when you type the url (http://localhost:5000/api/Home/HomeTest) directly into the browser?

Comment: Cold you please open the  URL from browser / postman and post the result as well. Seems like its a .net core error rather than angular one.

Comment: @user4596412, Please update question with the correct URL in the start of your post. You are missing `api/`. It confused me, might confuse other readers.

Comment: If the controller has a `Route` attribute, its value is prepended to the route template of child actions in that controller. So in your action's route template, you don't need to repeat the `api/[controller]` part.

Comment: How are you hosting the angular app?

Answer (score 2):

For the `Route` attribute confifuration in your Controller, the url called in the request should be `http://localhost:5000/api/Home/api/Home/HomeTest`.

Or you could change the `[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]` on the action with `[Route("/api/[controller]/[action]")]`, and then you could call the request with url `http://localhost:5000/api/Home/HomeTest`.

Refer to [Combining attribute routes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/routing?view=aspnetcore-3.1#combining-attribute-routes) for more details about the `Route` attribute.